# Angular - Error: $rootScope:infdig when setting a directive attribute using a controller variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive that prevents certain values from being entered into an input. For example this...

```
<input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue" 
    block="[0, 10, 17]" />
```

... will give a validation error if the user enters 0, 10, or 17.

This is working fine, but now I need to conditionally set the values being blocked depending on a variable in my controller, so I tried to use a ternary to set the value, like this...

```
<input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue" 
    block="blockValues ? [0, 10, 17] : []" />
```

However this is causing an [Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(c,e,f,g)%7Bf%3Dd%26%26g%3Fg%5B0%5D:a(c,e,f,g);return%20b(f,c,e)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D%5D), and I don't understand why. Could someone please explain this error to me and what I can do to fix it? Or any alternative would be appreciated as well. Thank you!

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []); 
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.blockValues = true;
    $scope.testValue = '';
});


myApp.directive('block', function() {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                block: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators.allowedValues = function (value) {
                    return !scope.block || scope.block.indexOf(value) === -1;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <!-- Errors -->
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        block="blockValues ? [0] : []" />

      <!-- No Errors
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        block="false ? [0] : []" />
      -->
      <!-- No Errors
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        block="true ? [0] : []" />
      -->
      <!-- No Errors
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        block="[0]" />
       -->
       <!-- No Errors
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        ng-min="blockValues ? 1 : 0" />
       -->      
    </form>
    <div>{{myForm.testValue.$error}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common mistake is binding to a function which generates a new array every time it is called. In this case a new array `[0]` is generated each time, creating an infinite digest error.

```
  <!-- Infinite Digest Errors
  <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
    block="blockValues ? [0] : []" />
  -->
```

Since it returns a new array, AngularJS determines that the model is different on each `$digest` cycle, resulting in the error. The solution is to return the same array object if the elements have not changed:

```
  <!-- FIXED -->
  <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
    ng-init="a1=[0];a0=[]" block="blockValues ? a1 : a0" />
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - $rootScope / infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D,%5B%7B%22msg%22:%22fn:%20function%20(a)%7Breturn%20d(a)%7D%22,%22newVal%22:%5B0%5D,%22oldVal%22:%5B0%5D%7D%5D%5D)

#### The Demo

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []); 
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.blockValues = true;
    $scope.testValue = '';
});


myApp.directive('block', function() {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                block: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$validators.allowedValues = function (value) {
                    return !scope.block || scope.block.indexOf(value) === -1;
                };
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <!-- Infinite Digest Errors
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        block="blockValues ? [0] : []" />
      -->

      <!-- FIXED -->
      <input type="number" name="testValue" ng-model="testValue"
        ng-init="a1=[0];a0=[]" block="blockValues ? a1 : a0" />
      
    </form>
    <div>{{myForm.testValue.$error}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I read that angular link 3 times and didn't put it together, thank you. One follow up question, why did `block="true ? [0] : []"` or `ng-min="blockValues ? 1 : 0"` not cause errors?

Comment: `1` and `0` are [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive). `[0]` is an object, a newly created object. `[0]` is not equal to `[0]` because they are different objects. See for yourself, `console.log([0] == [0])` prints `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I found using `ng-model-options` helped:

```
ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true, debounce: 200 }"
```

Read up on the docs more, here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions